# What Is xcdatamodel and what special steps must be taken to use source control with it?

Tags: ios, xcdatamodel

I have had nothing but trouble with the .xcdatamodel in my XCode ios project. 
I know it's a visual representation of my data model, but the XCode subversion support is weak at best, and whenever i want to attempt to merge or really do anything, if something goes wrong, it's usually the xcdatamodel. I fundamentally don't understand how to delete/move/update/ and use source control with this file.

Does anyone have any tips, because sometimes I find the .xcdatamodel or modelId files scattered throughout my code, inside a shared folder, or other times just in the project root.